# Is there a way to extract only keys using KV in logstash

Tags: logstash

Afetr Matching the below log line with grok got the message in "msg" and tried to use the KV plugin to extract fields.But also want all the Keys in array in one field,can you please suggest any way to do this?

Grok:
grok { match => [ "message","%{WORD}%{SPACE}[%{GREEDYDATA:ts}] \<%{DATA:user}> \<{ \"Response\":{%{GREEDYDATA:msg} } }>" ]

Filter:

```
kv{
    source=>"msg"
    target=>"response"
    trimkey=>" \""
    field_split => ","
    value_split => ":"
    trim => " \""
    }
```

STATUS   [04/06 18:36:28.114]  <{ "Response":{ "In":42, "Out":42, "A":1, "B":18, "C":7} }>

Comment: It might be interesting to know what you plan to do with such a array.

Comment: we want to use this Array in the Kibana to show after some modifications.In the Resposne i have given A,B,c as keys normally we will be getting some sources there according to our logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your kv{} filter is set to create fields like [response][in], etc.  You could drop into the ruby{} filter and loop across the keys that exist under the [response] field.

Comment: Thanks Collins,I will get from the ruby filter.whether we can use the KV inside ruby?

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment, but my suggestion was to use the kv{} filter and then use the ruby{} filter.